# How to call for object keys in javascript (codecademy)

Tags: javascript, object, key

I'm following an online course in Javascript from Codecademy but i'm stuck in an assignment.

I'm trying to list the firstName key from my "friends list".
I have to do this with a "for in" statement in a function.
The firstName key is within the object "Steve", which in in an object "Friends".
This is the code that i have at the moment:

```
var friends = {
    steve: {
        firstName: 'Steve',
        lastName: 'Jobs',
        number: '1',
        address: ['Fregataan','65','8546','RG','Amsterdam','The Netherlands'],
    },

    bill: {
        firstName: 'Bill',
        lastName: 'Gates',
        number: '2',
        address: ['Fregataan','665','8546','RG','Amsterdam','The Netherlands'],
    },

};

function list(friends){
    for (var firstName in friends){
        console.log(friends.keys(firstName))
    }
}

 list(friends.keys);
```

This is the assignment I get from the course: 
1. Create a function list that takes a single parameter.
2. In the body of the function, write a for/in loop.
3. In the loop, use console.log to print out the key. (For example, if you only have bill and steve as entries, list should just print out "bill" and "steve".)

The object "friends" was already written in a previous assignment. The function has to be written in this assignment. Can someone please find my mistake and tell me what i did wrong?

Greetings,
Luuk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be a tricky question. You are trying to print the firstName key which (if done correctly) will print out "Steve" and "Bill", but the assignment, as you described it, is to print out the key (i.e. "steve" and "bill"). So if that's the case, you should just print out the key:

```
function list(friends){
    for (var key in friends){
        console.log(key);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should play around with it a bit more.
No need to use 'keys'.

```
var friends = {
    steve: {
        firstName: 'Steve',
        lastName: 'Jobs',
        number: '1',
        address: ['Fregataan','65','8546','RG','Amsterdam','The Netherlands'],
    },

    bill: {
        firstName: 'Bill',
        lastName: 'Gates',
        number: '2',
        address: ['Fregataan','665','8546','RG','Amsterdam','The Netherlands'],
    },

};

function list(friends){
    console.log(friends);
    for (var friend in friends){
        console.log(friend);

        var f = friends[friend];
        console.log(f.firstName);
    }
}

list(friends);
```

Comment: This gave the wrong output. It gave the output 2 times and the output included the 2 objects + the names of the friends. So it had the right output but with too much information.